# Using Web3JS to sign tx: default return value of chainID is networkID (which can be different); does this not create a replay issue?

Tags: web3js, signature

[EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) requires that transactions be signed using the ChainID as one of the parameter.
[Web3JS Sign Transaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=chainid#signtransaction) document shows that the ChainID will be automatically fetched using `web3.eth.net.getId()`

[Web3JS getID](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-shh.html#net-getid) (which is supposed to fetch the chainID automatically) is actually returning the `NetworkID` and not the `ChainID`.

Considering this and this [blog post](https://medium.com/@pedrouid/chainid-vs-networkid-how-do-they-differ-on-ethereum-eec2ed41635b) that shows that not all EVM based chains have the same `NetworkID` and `ChainID`.  This will create an issue right?